# Serif blackboard fonts in matplotlib

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib, latex

Matplotlib's blackboard LaTeX fonts seem to be sans-serif:

[image: E rendered using mathbb in matplotlib]

This contrasts badly with pdfLaTeX's default rendition:

[image: E rendered using mathbb in LaTeX]

Can I force matplotlib to use serif blackboard fonts?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize fonts, colors, line weights, etc. using a [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) file. The sample they give is pretty huge, but scroll down a ways and you'll find the options for LaTeX. Once you have your file customized, save it in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` and it'll be read automatically next time you import matplotlib.

Comment: I know this page, but i haven't found anything that relates specifically to the fonts used by `mathbb`...

Comment: What about `mathtext.default`? I haven't done any of this type of configuration, but I came across the options when I was trying to set defaults for the standard (non-math/TeX) fonts...

Comment: Oh, OK. Sorry I couldn't be of more help